# Несколько вопросов по ORM

Tags: c#, .net, orm

В общем, описал все сущности БД в виде отдельных классов.

Для каждой сущности создал собственный класс Provider, который описывает CRUD операции.

Подскажите, стоит ли все Provider'ы объединять в нечто более, например в DbProvider, который содержит в себе все провайдеры к сущностям?

В каком месте лучше задавать логику порядок вставки данных в сущности?

Как лучше описать связи между сущностями?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте зайти с другой стороны, и посмотреть, что сейчас существует для работы с БД. Например, для этого очень хорошо подходит книга [Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1616782/) за авторством коллектива разработчиков, главный из которых Мартин Фаулер.

В книге большую часть занимает описания паттернов для работы с БД. Кроме того, книга вводит *стандартные* названия для этих паттернов. То, что вы назвали **провайдером**, скорее всего является **хранилищем** (repository). Использование единой терминологии упрощает понимание. Кроме того, там описаны важные **построители запросов** (query builders), **преобразователи данных** (data mappers) и **единицы работы** (units of work).

Если вы пишите ORM самостоятельно, вам, несомненно, потребуется всё это реализовать. Второе соображение — можно посмотреть на существующие ORM, и определить, как эти вопросы решаются там. Например, в Entity Framework есть понятие **наборов данных** (`DbSet<TEntity>`). Это не паттерн, это название класса, в котором реализованы сразу несколько паттернов, и, в частности, хранилища.

Все они объединены в класс `DbContext`, который является аналогом вашего `DbProvider`. Он также реализует несколько паттернов, в том числе **единицу работы**. Вся логика вставки реализована в единице работы, в методе `DbContext.SaveChanges`. Сначала с помощью `DbSet<TEntity>.Add` надо *зарегистрировать* в контексте новые объекты, а затем вызвать `DbContext.SaveChanges`, который решит, что надо записать сначала, а что потом.

Контекст также выполняет обратную операцию заполнения объектов значениями из таблиц, то есть реализует паттерн **преобразователь данных**. Я не смотрел глубоко в код, но, насколько я понимаю, используется один универсальный преобразователь для всех таблиц и классов.

И последний вопрос — о связях между сущностями. В EF и NHibernate связи реализуются с помощью так называемых *навигационных свойств*:

```
[Table("Categories")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

В данном примере все свойства напрямую отображаются на поля в таблицах, кроме двух *навигационных*: `Category.Products` и `Product.Category`. При этом EF сам понимает, что эти свойства навигационные и их не надо загружать из базы или сохранять в ней. Также он понимает, что речь идёт о связи один-ко-многим и что связь происходит по полю `Product.CategoryId`. Впрочем, как видно из примера, умолчания EF можно менять с помощью атрибутов.

EF реализует паттерн **ленивая загрузка** (lazy loading), поэтому при определённых условиях можно *подгружать* объекты, доступные через навигационные свойства. Если это окажется слишком медленным, можно дать подсказку EF, какие объекты потребуются точно, и которые лучше подгрузить сразу.

Возможно, в вашей ORM нужно ориентироваться на подобные решения. Или для начала поиграться с существующими ORM, такими как Entity Framework, NHibernate, Dapper. Возможно, вы откажитесь от идеи создавать собственную ORM, поскольку большая часть того, что вам нужно, уже реализована.